# Route Model Binding returns just one record in Laravel

Tags: routes, controller, laravel-8, data-retrieval, route-model-binding

I have a table (post) in my database with (id, title, post) columns.
I have 3 records with the same title in my table but, it returns just the first record.
How to return all records with the same title using Route Model Binding?

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('bind/{key:title}',[RouteModelBindingController::class, 'index']);
```

This is my Controller Class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;
class RouteModelBindingController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Post $key){
      return $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: route model binding don't work like that....(Post $key) will only return for one Post elocuent model, and you want retrieve a collection of Post models. I suggest you read documentation, see examples of crud and try to refactor your code